# "can not be used when making a shared object" while building glibc

Tags: linux, gcc, glibc

I am compiling glibc 2.19 on Debian 9.8 (x64), but I got the following error after running `make`. How to fix this?

```
gcc -B/usr/bin/ -nostdlib -nostartfiles -o /home/cyril/HME/Multcore_version/AHME/glibc-build/iconv/iconv_prog    -Wl,-z,combreloc -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--hash-style=both /home/cyril/HME/Multcore_version/AHME/glibc-build/csu/crt1.o /home/cyril/HME/Multcore_version/AHME/glibc-build/csu/crti.o `gcc -B/usr/bin/  --print-file-name=crtbegin.o` /home/cyril/HME/Multcore_version/AHME/glibc-build/iconv/iconv_prog.o /home/cyril/HME/Multcore_version/AHME/glibc-build/iconv/iconv_charmap.o /home/cyril/HME/Multcore_version/AHME/glibc-build/iconv/charmap.o /home/cyril/HME/Multcore_version/AHME/glibc-build/iconv/charmap-dir.o /home/cyril/HME/Multcore_version/AHME/glibc-build/iconv/linereader.o /home/cyril/HME/Multcore_version/AHME/glibc-build/iconv/dummy-repertoire.o /home/cyril/HME/Multcore_version/AHME/glibc-build/iconv/simple-hash.o /home/cyril/HME/Multcore_version/AHME/glibc-build/iconv/xstrdup.o /home/cyril/HME/Multcore_version/AHME/glibc-build/iconv/xmalloc.o  -Wl,-dynamic-linker=/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -Wl,-rpath-link=/home/cyril/HME/Multcore_version/AHME/glibc-build:/home/cyril/HME/Multcore_version/AHME/glibc-build/math:/home/cyril/HME/Multcore_version/AHME/glibc-build/elf:/home/cyril/HME/Multcore_version/AHME/glibc-build/dlfcn:/home/cyril/HME/Multcore_version/AHME/glibc-build/nss:/home/cyril/HME/Multcore_version/AHME/glibc-build/nis:/home/cyril/HME/Multcore_version/AHME/glibc-build/rt:/home/cyril/HME/Multcore_version/AHME/glibc-build/resolv:/home/cyril/HME/Multcore_version/AHME/glibc-build/crypt:/home/cyril/HME/Multcore_version/AHME/glibc-build/nptl /home/cyril/HME/Multcore_version/AHME/glibc-build/libc.so.6 /home/cyril/HME/Multcore_version/AHME/glibc-build/libc_nonshared.a -Wl,--as-needed /home/cyril/HME/Multcore_version/AHME/glibc-build/elf/ld.so -Wl,--no-as-needed -lgcc  `gcc -B/usr/bin/  --print-file-name=crtend.o` /home/cyril/HME/Multcore_version/AHME/glibc-build/csu/crtn.o

/usr/bin/ld: /home/cyril/HME/Multcore_version/AHME/glibc-build/csu/crt1.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol `__libc_csu_fini' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/crtbegin.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against hidden symbol `__TMC_END__' can not be used when making a shared object

/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output

/usr/bin/ld: /home/cyril/HME/Multcore_version/AHME/glibc-build/csu/crt1.o: relocation R_X86_64_32S against symbol `__libc_csu_fini' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6/crtbegin.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against hidden symbol `__TMC_END__' can not be used when making a shared object

/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Nonrepresentable section on output

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: It's not inconceivable that a 5 year old software release might have trouble compiling on a much more recent OS. Can you compile the current glibc version?

Comment: @Shawn The latest version of glibc can be compiled succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Your GCC is configured to produce position-independent executables by default. But the `Makefile` for GLIBC-2.19 is not prepared for such configuration.

Step 1: verify that the PIE part is true:

```
echo "int main() { return 0; }" | gcc -xc - &&
file ./a.out
```

It should say "shared library" or "position independent executable".

Step 2: you can fix the GLIBC-2.19 built by adding `-no-pie` to `LDFLAGS`.

Comment: I added `LDFLAGS="$LDFLAGS -no-pie` to the bottom of the `configue` file, and the error still exists. Did I modify the wrong file?

Comment: @L.Ward Maybe -- look at the failing command line. Does it have `-no-pie` flag?

Comment: There is no `-no-pie` flag.

Comment: @L.Ward "There is no ..." -- well, that's your answer. Somehow you need to get it in there. Read the `Makefile` and figure it out.